# Entity Framework Fluent API Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Let's assume I have these tables:**

```
Role
- RoleId
- Name

UserRole
- UserId
- RoleId

User
- UserId
- Username

UserEmail
- UserId
- EmailId
- IsPrimary

Email
- EmailId
- Address
```

**Now my model, should look something like this:**

```
public class Role {
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserEmail> UserEmails { get; set; }
}

public class UserEmail {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Email Email { get; set; }
}

public class Email {
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserEmail> UserEmails { get; set; }
}
```

**These are common and specific things I would like to do in this particular case:**

**Add the primary keys:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey(q => q.RoleId);
```

Will this have the same *effect* than using the `Key` attribute in the entity property? If so, why bother using the `modelBuilder` when using *Data Annotations* is shorter and easier to read/write? Is there any *convention* on when to use *Data Annotations* or *Fluent API*?

**Add many to many relationships:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
    .HasMany(q => q.Users)
    .WithMany(q => q.Roles)
    .Map(q => {
                  q.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                  q.MapRightKey("UserId");
                  q.ToTable("UserRoles");
              });
```

**Add one to many relationships:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserEmail>()
    .HasRequired(q => q.User)
    .WithMany(q => q.UserEmails)
    .HasForeignKey(q => q.EmailId);
```

Is the last line required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that `HasKey` method has the same effect as the `[Key]` attribute. You might have a lot of configuration to do and prefer to keep it all in the `ModelBuilder` method. On the other hand you might have very little or prefer to use the attributes for some of it. Just gives you some flexibility.

If you're talking about the:

`.HasForeignKey(q => q.EmailId);`

Then in your case, yes it is required. Why? Because you've created your own foreign key property in the `UserEmail` entity. If you deleted the property you could remove this line and EF would create one for you in the database called `Email_Id`. You could still access this through the navigation property `instanceOfUserEmail.Email.EmailId`.